# Leave atleast one of several Xamarin Switchs toggled on?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, switch-statement

I don't want an user to be able to start a quiz without selecting at least one topic.

How can I make sure at least one switch is toggled?

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwfTx.png)

Xaml:

```
    <StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,20">
    <Entry x:Name="nameEntry"
           Placeholder="Enter name" />
    <Label Text="Math"/>
    <Switch Toggled="Switcher_Toggled" ClassId="Math"/>
    <Label Text="History"/>
    <Switch Toggled="Switcher_Toggled" ClassId="History"/>
    <Button x:Name="StartButton" Clicked="OnStartButtonClicked" Text="Start Quiz"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Xaml.cs:

```
void Switcher_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    var switchItem = (Switch)sender;
    if (!e.Value)
    {
        SelectedCategories.categories.Remove(switchItem.ClassId);
    }

    else
    {
        SelectedCategories.categories.Add(switchItem.ClassId);

    }
}
```

Simple enough. So, whats the practical solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to count the SelectedCategories

```
if( SelectedCategories.Count > 0 ){
```

You probably want a check round the Add to check the same ClassId isn't added twice depending on whats calling it and how.

Answer (score 0):

The below code just works for me. It just restricts any logic to executed when no switches are toggled.

```
//XAML code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Demo.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,20">
        <Entry x:Name="nameEntry" Placeholder="Enter name" />
        <Label Text="Math"/>
        <Switch x:Name="Math" Toggled="Switcher_Toggled" ClassId="Math" />
        <Label Text="History"/>
        <Switch x:Name="History" Toggled="Switcher_Toggled" ClassId="History"/>
        <Button x:Name="StartButton" Clicked="OnStartButtonClicked" Text="Start Quiz"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

//XAML code behind logic.
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<string> SelectedCategories { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SelectedCategories = new List<string>();
    }

    private void OnStartButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Math.IsToggled || this.History.IsToggled)
        {
            this.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Quiz Started..!", "OK");
        }
    }

    private void Switcher_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        var switchItem = (Switch)sender;
        if (!e.Value)
        {
            SelectedCategories.Remove(switchItem.ClassId);
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedCategories.Add(switchItem.ClassId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need Toggled events so I can add their names to List<string>categories

Comment: @mm_archeris: I have edited the solution and it works perfectly for me.